# print 'something' if all conditions in an if-else statement are empty

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have a function in a bash script that does a `diff` on files. I have set to `echo` the `diff` if one exists, however if none exist I would like to only print out `"No differences found in ANY Task Definitions"`

Here is what I have;

```
diff_taskDef () {
MAS=master.json
CUR=current.json
clear
mapfile -t awsReg < <(ls ~/regions)
for awsrg in "${awsReg[@]}"; do
 mapfile -t awsTD < <(ls ~/regions/"$awsrg")
    for td in "${awsTD[@]}"; do
     DIFF="$(diff -q ~/regions/"$awsrg"/"$td"/"$td"-"$MAS" ~/regions/"$awsrg"/"$td"/"$td"-"$CUR")"
       echo "$DIFF"
    done
done
```

So rather than a blank screen, or scrolling through EVERY statement without a positive `diff` saying `"no diff found"` I just want one if nothing is different

Comment: Don't use `ls` like this. `awsReg=(~/regions/*)`. In addition to being correct for all valid file names, you don't have to add `~/regions/` back to the names when iterating over them.

Answer (score 2):

Start by assuming no diff will be found. If you ever find a diff, change the value of the flag `diff_found`. You can stop looking for more diffs if you like at that point.

```
diff_taskDef () {
  MAS=master.json
  CUR=current.json
  clear
  diff_found=false
  for awsrg in ~/regions/*; do
    for td in "$awsrg"/*; do
      if ! diff -q "$td-$MAS" "$td/$td-$CUR"; then
          diff_found=true
          break 2  # optional
      fi
    done
  done
  if [[ $diff_found = false ]]; then
    echo "No differences found"
  fi
}
```

Comment: That looks good apart from it misses a directory; /home/ec2-user/regions/eu-west-1/audience-view-dev-api/audience-view-dev-api-master.json

Comment: ...also there's no message when the files are the same. The echo "No differences found" doesn't appear